# Convert DTS to AC3 but only if there is no AC3 track already present in container

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, dts

I have sound system that does not support DTS only AC3. I'm automating the process using bash that detects when movie was added to folder, downloads subtitles and converts audio track to AC3 using this command (one part of it):

`ffmpeg -i "{{episode}}" -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k "{{directory}}"/{{episode_name}}temp2.mkv`

This works without issue and I end up with a .mkv file that contains original DTS audio track and newly created AC3 audio track. The issue is that some files already contain both AC3 and DTS tracks and in those cases I end up with two AC3 tracks and one DTS track. Another issue is that this command is triggered every time there is update to subtitles. So it's possible that the command will execute multiple times in a period of a few days and the container will have X number of the AC3 tracks.

I need a way to detect if file already contains AC3 track before I initiate command from above, but I'm not sure what the command would be. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to consult somebody else for bash scripting, but `ffprobe -of flat -loglevel quiet -show_entries stream=codec_name -select_streams a {{episode}}` will output a `streams.stream.#.codec_name="xxx"` line per audio stream.  So, you can pipe its stdout and check for any line ending with `"ac3"`.

Comment: This would be more compact: `CODECS=$(ffprobe -show_entries stream=codec_name -loglevel quiet -of compact=p=0:nk=1 {{episode}})` with CODECS gets string with each line containing audio codec names